# $\hat{A}$-genus of a complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, characteristic-classes, index-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the Riemann-Roch-Hirzebruch theorem using the index theorem (*Heat Kernel and Dirac operators*, [BGV]), and at the end they say that since $$TM \otimes \mathbb{C} = T^{1,0}M \oplus T^{0,1}M, $$
with $M$ a Kähler manifold, then

$$ \hat{A}(TM) = \det \left( \frac{R^+}{e^{\frac{R^+}{2}}-e^{\frac{-R^+}{2}}} \right), $$

with $R^+$ is the curvature of the bundle $T^{1,0}M$ and knowing that the defintion of the $\hat{A}$-genus is

$$ \hat{A}(TM) :=  \sqrt{\det \left( \frac{R/2}{\sinh \left( R/2 \right) } \right)}, $$

with $R$ the Riemannian curvature of $M$.

But unfortunately, I do not see how that works. Any help would be nice, thank you.

Comment: See Proposition 11.14 in the book "Spin Geometry" by Lawson and Michelsohn

Comment: I hope you don't mind me fixing the LaTeX a little bit.

Comment: @YangMills Thanks, can’t wait to see if I can find the book tomorrow at university

Comment: @M.G. well thanks, much better now

Comment: @YangMills Just saw it but i do not understand how it gives the link between $R^+$ and $R$. Do $R^+$ and $R^-$ have the same trace ?